# Hello_World is a word in Python, it is different in an other mode. How I change it?

Tags: python, emacs

In python mode, when I `forward-word`. The cursor jumps from `H` to `d` (Hello_World). But in another mode(`shell-mode` or `c-mode`), the cursor jumps from `H` to `_`.

I want the result which i get in Python mode, even in the other mode. What should I do?

PS: I saw a similar question before, I have searched, but I could't find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

Underscores will be treated as part of a word. This command will change the [syntax table](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsSyntaxTable) of the mode you're currently in. AFAIK there's no way to change syntax globally. However, you could try modifying the standard syntax table. Most major modes inherit the standard-syntax-table.

```
(modify-syntax-entry  ?_ "w" standard-syntax-table)
```

If that doesn't work, I guess you have to add mode-hooks for all modes you're using and modify their syntax tables individually.

Answer (score 2):

Things got a little simpler since Emacs 24.4. There's now a `M-x superword-mode` that has the desired effect.